# Can a programming language still be called "typed" if it have data types but does not have operator overloading?

Tags: c, types, compiler-construction, programming-languages, terminology

If we have a programming language that force you to set the data types for the variables, for example:

```
int i;
float f;
```

But does not have operator overloading, so for example instead of using the `+` operator to add an `int` to an `int` or a `float` to a `float`, you would instead have an operator to add an `int` to an `int` (for example: `+`), and a different operator to add a `float` to a `float` (for example: `#+`).

Note that this programming language still have type safety, so for example if you tried to use the `#+` operator to add a `float` to an `int`, you would get a compilation error.

Can such a programming language still be called a "typed" programming language?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: How do you define "operator overloading" in your question. For example, `unsigned char` addition (`+`) could produce different results than `int` addition (consider `200 + 56`, in `int` you get `256` but for `unsigned char` you get `0`)... isn't that "operator overloading"?

Comment: in an untyped language you can do `i = 42; i = "foo"; i = -2.71828;` ... `i` has no type

Comment: @sepp2k What if the programming language forced you to set the data types for the variables, but did not have operator overloading and type safety, can we still call this language a "typed" programming language? (I think the answer is No, because even though we labeled each variable with a data type, we are not using this data type to implement operator overloading or enforce type safety, so we might as well not label the variables with any data type).

Comment: @Myst In my language there would be a third operator to add an `unsigned char` to an `unsigned char` (for example: `$+`), and as you have said, if we added `200 + 56` as `unsigned char` addition, the result will be `0`.

Comment: One might ask why a language designer would ignore the type information and force the programmer to choose integer addition versus floating-point addition when there was only one possible choice for the presented operands.

Comment: Huh? Is, say, OCaml typed? @another-dave - there is a lot of very good reasons to do so. E.g., type inference works better if there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @SK-logic -  if the language has float and int, and objects are declared as such, I am asking why it would not infer from context the operation requested by (say) "+".  It's not clear why type inference (by which I understand a determination of operand types from context) impinges on this. Could you enlighten me? A link will do. Thanks.

Comment: @another-dave and what if you *do not declare* types? E.g., consider the following ML function: `let f x y = x + y`. What is its type? Without overloading, it's obviously `int -> int -> int`. With overloading it's, well, complicated. See the following for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Overloading

Comment: I'm talking only in the context of the original question: "a programming language that forces you to set the data types".

Comment: Strange to have types but forbid them to use them. So very hypothetical.

Comment: The notation of ```#+``` for floating add suggests this might relate to BCPL, but AFAIK even with floating-point extensions, it does not have type declarations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't really seem to be about practical programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Typing has to do with each value having a specific type associated with it (int, float, string).  It has nothing to do with **which** operations can be used on those values.

Comment: Hm, if I read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) correctly, a set of valid operations is an important property of type.

Comment: It is true that a type's definition should include which operations are available for the type.  However, the operations themselves don't affect whether the language is "typed" or not.

Comment: It would be nice to see a prooflink for this statement in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

short answer: yes

longer answer: typed languages allow you to specify the domain of values a variable has based in its type.

operator overloading may require a typed language but is not part of the definition of typed languages.

So if it has operator overloading based on type, it is a typed language but if it doesn't have operator overloading it still might be a typed language.